# How to display the number of line which the highlighted words was found when i push a button?

Tags: c#

//searching and highlighting the word

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string[] show = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("\n", " ").Split(' ');
        string type = textBox1.Text;
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < show.Length; i++)
        {
            if (show[i] == textBox1.Text)
            {
                n++;
            }
        }
        this.label1.Text = n.ToString();
        this.label2.Text = str;
 }
```

//finding all the words and display the line

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

I want to open a new form when I push a button and it will display the number of line the highlighted word was located and the word itself just like in notepad++.

Comment: proper code Indentation will help us understand the code. please do it.

Comment: button2_Click just counts how often the searchtext is found. There has to be more code with which you highlight the strings. Also what is `type` used for and where does `str` come from in that function?

Comment: str was initialized globally. type wasn't included I just forgot to delete that. there are codes sir. but it is in a textbox when I type something in the textbox it will highlight that word.

Answer (score 0):

As said right now this code only counts the appearances. No highlighting is done here. But if you want to get the line number you can do the following:

The `string[] show` contains each line of your input as a sepperate entry. 
So when you loop through it and get a hit, you just have to save the index `i` (in a list for example).

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        List<int> lineNo = new List<int>();
        string[] show = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("\n", " ").Split(' ');
        string type = textBox1.Text;
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < show.Length; i++)
        {
            if (show[i] == textBox1.Text)
            {
                n++;
                lineNo.Add(i);
            }
        }
        this.label1.Text = n.ToString();
        this.label2.Text = str;
 }
```

In the end you will have all line numbers in the List `lineNo` and can work with them further.

Dont know enough about forms, so i cant tell how to highlight them.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: sir I want it to look like the find function in notepad++ where if you push the button find all in open documents it will pop up what line the word is located and the word itself.

Comment: My code will give you all lines that are found in `lineNo`. You have to loop through this List and highlight the linenumber that you get. As said i dont know much about forms and cant tell you how that would work tho. You should show what you tried for this task and maybe someone else can help you further from there